# can not change the (not the last) pushed commit message

Tags: git

I wan't to change a commit message which is been pushed and its not the last commit.
As git documents suggested i just done the rebase as follow:

```
rebase -i HEAD~2
```

then edited the result as follows:

```
reword e499d89 some thig been done
pick 0c39034 some other thing been done
```

then saved the commit list file successfuly and after that edit of the reworded commit would prompted as follow:

```
some thig been done
#some comments here
-->list of changelist here
```

i edited the commit message and save it, but after all idea git log shows no change in git commits and their messages.

**Finally** the problem was because of commit message text, due to integration of issue tracker and git server we add issue id after a sharp sign in start of any commit so the commit would look like this:

```
#123 some thing been done
```

then in final phase of editing the commit message, the entire commit message was interpreted as another comment line (i suppose):

```
    #123 some thig been done
    #some comments here
    -->list of changelist here
```

So, just adding a space before sharp sign solved the problem and new commit been created:

```
 #123 some thig been done
#some comments here
-->list of changelist here
```

P.S: I don't know if it could be called a bug of git or not?!

Comment: Git commits are read-only. When you change commit, then you essentially create new commit with new message. Old commits are still here unchanged.

Comment: I did the same thing as you described, but it works fine, the commit message has been updated. Could you should the `git log` before and after the rebase?

Comment: no new commits been created either

Comment: @redbeard1970 Show transcript of operation.

Comment: thanks, the problem was the commit message text, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

After passing all operations: *rewording* -> typing the new commit message -> saving the file -> closing the file
You should *force-push* the amended commit to change the commit history:

```
$ git push --force
```

Comment: shouldn't the new commits been added to local branch? No new commits been added to git history (local) so nothing to push?

Comment: @redbeard1970, You've wrote: *change a commit message which is been pushed*. Been pushed, so to change the history it should force push over the old commit

Comment: the problem is i change the commit messages but the change not been applied at all, so nothing to push

Comment: thanks, I was doing just as the article said, the problem was commit message, check the updated question again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the commit log is `A-B-C-D-E<-master` and you want to modify C's commit message.

```
git checkout master
git reset C --hard
git commit --amend
#modify the change commit message, save and quit
git cherry-pick C..E
#or git cherry-pick D E
#or git cherry-pick D;git cherry-pick E
git push origin -f master:master
```

If others have cloned or fetched your previous `master`, you need to notify them to update `master` to the latest version.

Suppose they have local `master` as `A-B-C-D-E-F-G`.

```
git fetch origin master
git reset B --hard
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
git cherry-pick F G
```